# Generic type-casting method returning an Optional object

Tags: java, generics, java-8, option-type

I have a method:

```
public LoadService {
    public <T> T load(String blobId, Class<T> objectClass) {
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

That allows me to invoke it like so:

```
Fizz fizz = loadService.load("12345", Fizz.class);
Buzz buzz = loadService.load("23456", Buzz.class);
```

And this is great. **Except**, now, I want `load(...)` to return an `Optional<???>` so that the interaction would look something like:

```
Optional<Fizz> maybeFizz = loadService.load("12345", Fizz.class);
if (maybeFizz.isPresent()) {
   // etc.
}

Optional<Buzz> maybeBuzz = loadService.load("23456", Buzz.class);
if (maybeBuzz.isPresent()) {
   // etc.
}
```

What changes I need to make to `load(...)` method to make it capable of returning an `Optional` of `<T>`?

Comment: `public <T> Optional<T> load(String blobId, Class<T> objectClass) {`? But I think this probably won't be very useful unless you also show the body of `load`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by declaring something like this.

```java
public static <T> Optional<T> load(Object something, Class<T> clazz){
  return Optional.of((T)something);
}
```

Comment: should be `Optional.ofNullable(..)`

Comment: I said `like` because is just an example of how to do it.

Comment: If you want to remove the warning about the unchecked cast, turn `(T)something` into `class.cast(something)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can type-cast the given object inside the `load()` method either like that:

```
T result = (T) myObject;
```

or by making use of the of `cast()` method of the `Class<T>` class:

```
T result = objectClass.cast(myObject);
```

The only difference that in the first case, the compiler will issue a warning for unchecked type-cast.

In order to create an optional object from the nullable value, you have to use the static method [`Optional.ofNullable()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable(T)) which will create an empty optional if the given value is `null`. Conversely, method `Optional.of()` with throw a `NullPointerException` if you pass a `null` reference to it.

So the return clause of your method might be written like this:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(objectClass.cast(myObject));
```

or

```
return Optional.ofNullable((T) myObject);
```